# upgrading matplotlib permission error even as admin

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, installation, upgrade

I'm running python 2.7 on Windows 7, setup via Anaconda. I wanted to update my matplotlib by running pip install matplotlib --upgrade and received the following error message:

> C:\Windows\system32>pip install matplotlib Downloading/unpacking
>   matplotlib Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   numpy>=1.6 in c:\anaco nda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   pyparsing>=1.5.6 in c: \anaconda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
>   python-dateutil in c:\ anaconda\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
>   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in
>   c:\anaconda\li b\site-packages (from matplotlib) Requirement already
>   satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4 in c:\anacond
>   a\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) Installing collected packages:
>   matplotlib Cleaning up... Exception: Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
>   122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in
>   run
>
> ```
> requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_p ath)   File
> ```
>
> "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1435, in install
>       requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 671, in install
>       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 901, in
>   move_wheel_files
>
> ```
> pycompile=self.pycompile,   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 215, in
> ```
>
> move_wheel_fil es
>       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 209, in clobber
>       shutil.copy2(srcfile, destfile)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
>       copyfile(src, dst)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
>       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\matplo tlib\ft2font.pyd'

I gave myself 'full control' by right clicking on the Anaconda folder, going to the security tab and changing the permissions. I also restarted my command window as an administrator. (The account I use is an administrator, but in light of: [What precisely does 'Run as administrator' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986971/what-precisely-does-run-as-administrator-do) I thought it couldn't hurt)

Despite these two steps I'm still getting an IOError: [Errno13] on the cleaning up step. I can no longer import matplotlib. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib. I hope to avoid doing that for Anaconda.